# How to format an internal Hard Disk Drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have Kubuntu 22.04 on my internal SSD. I wish to format the 1.8TiB spinning HDD in order to use it as storage. I've tried using the partition manager but I end up with a partition that I cannot write to.

I get the message "Access denied. Cannot write to ..."

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This is probably a permissions issue. Have you confirmed that the disk (or a directory on that disk) is owned by your user account?